# How to save the whole raw email on the file system?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, mime-mail

I should save the entire structure of the emails that arrive at a mail server.
Using the "poco ++" libraries I was unable to save the email entirely in the file system. For the moment inside the class that inherits from MailMessage I am doing this:

**MyMailMessage.h**

```
class MyMailMessage: public MailMessage {
  public:
    bool WriteRawContent(int i);
};
```

**MyMailMessage.cpp**

```
bool MyMailMessage::WriteRawContent(int i)
{
  std::cout << "Write Raw Content" << std::endl;
  std::ofstream outfile("email.eml");
  MessageHeader messageheader;
  if(isMultipart()){
    writeMultipart(messageheader, outfile);
  }
  else{
    write(outfile);
  }
  std::cout << "Wrote it" << std::endl;
  outfile.close();
  return true;
}
```

With the write method I can only save a part:

```
Return-Path: <mail-test@cartellini.info>
Delivered-To: mail-test2@cartellini.info
Received: from server.mail  (unknown [122.130.30.20])   by server.mail 
Message-ID: <12314142test@webmail.it>
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 12:41:28 +0200
Subject: test_subject
From: email-test@webmail.com
To: email-test2@webmail.com
User-Agent: Web-mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_20220810124128_35847"
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Importance: Normal

------=_20220810124128_35847--
```

and with the writeMultiPart method:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_20220810124128_35847"
Mime-Version: 1.0


------=_20220810124128_35847--
```

**I have to save the entire email** with also the contents of the attachment or attachments in binary (and of the body if it is sent) like so :

```
Return-Path: <mail-test@webmail.com>
Delivered-To: mail-test2@webmail.com
Message-ID: <232131mail-test@webmail.com>
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 12:41:28 +0200
Subject: test_subject
From: mail-test@webmail.com
To: mail-test2@webmail.com
User-Agent: WebMail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="----=_20220211113523_23522"
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Importance: Normal

------=_20220211113523_23522
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


------=_20220211113523_23522
Content-Type: text/html; name="example.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.html"
<html>
<head><title>Email from webmail server</title></head>
<body>
<br>
Hi email test
</body>
</html>
------=_20220211113523_23522
Content-Type: application/xml; name="example.xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.xml"

PDS9DSAKQWEK123òSAD9213031ASDKSADSAKA9DSSDAU1293219KSADSAKSDA9213
PD93MNbnasdoaKSDAOWEQLDOWQELDWQDOSAD.SAD
```

so that it is possible to pass the file to the email decryption function and read it later as if it were going to read it directly from the email server.

**EDIT**

as suggested by @GusEvan i implemented latest function

```
void retrieveMessage(
    int id,
    std::ostream & ostr
);
```

To backup the email in raw format and then process it.
Here is the working version of the snippet:

```
POP3ClientSession ppcs(MAIL_SERVER);
std::ofstream outfile("email.eml");
std::ifstream infile("email.eml");
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= messageInfoVec.size(); i++) {
      ppcs.retrieveMessage(i,outfile);
      mailMessage.read(infile,partHandler);
      ProcessEmail(mailMessage,partHandler);
      outfile.close();
      infile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last retrieveMessage() overloaded method should be for you.

```
void retrieveMessage(
    int id,
    MailMessage & message,
    PartHandler & handler
);
```

> Retrieves the raw message with the given id from the server and copies it to the given output stream.

Check the documentation:

https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Net.POP3ClientSession.html#27007